# How to show portion of the form capable of add or already added item to view or edit in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms

---

### user enter **Cat** info and select '**yes**'

Participant Info

- Name :**Cat**
- Email : **cat@email.com**

Do you like to add another participant?
**yes**/no

---

### in the following, user enter **Dog** info and says **yes**

**Cat (hyper link to view/edit)**

Participant Info

- Name :**Dog**
- Email : **dog@email.com**

Do you like to add another participant?
**yes**/no

---

in the following, user click **Cat** from list to either edit or view

---

- [Cat](http://google.com)
- [Dog](http://www.apple.com)

Participant Info

- Name :
- Email :

Do you like to add another participant?
yes/no

---

in the following, user see Cat Info can just view/Edit

---

**Cat**

- **Name :Cat**
- **Email : cat@email.com**

[Dog](http://www.apple.com)

Participant Info

- Name :
- Email :

Do you like to add another participant?
yes/no

---

I would like to do the portion of form submission using asp.net / c# , can I use session instead of DB. I would appreciate if I guide on how to implement this ?
Also other portion of the form should be linear on the same page or multi page/multi step and on the bottom submit button will trigger email with all the user entered info.

Comment: use Ajax, dont use session if you're using a loadbalancer.

Comment: @Stefan Could you give me simple example code snippet to start using Ajax?

Comment: Hmm, on second thought: you might just want to start with basic form submission. Its easier than the use of AJAX

Comment: are you using MVC? an single page application? .net core? if you use it in an internet search youll find tons of examples

Comment: @Stefan it will be simple form submission and all the data captured will be sent as email when submit clicked. I would like to implement the above scenario in simplest way using asp.net /c# (.net framework) . All I need some one enters info and want to view/edit while the form submission not done yet,  how do I present that user entered data within a form? example would be easy for me to understand.

Comment: @Stefan how would you call this type of forms ?

Comment: I understand but if you let me know what you're using I can point you to a tutorial

Comment: Here are some examples https://www.codeproject.com/articles/1078491/creating-forms-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: @Stefan currently I have very basic form in aspx file , but I want to implement above scenario into that form, I would like to see that portion as example code, I checked your example project but still not understand how can I use it for my scenario

Comment: Take a look at this for ASPX and forms: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-pages/overview/getting-started/introducing-aspnet-web-pages-2/form-basics. Here's an example of sending form data to email: https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/41/send-form-content-by-email-in-asp-net